# How to redirect to another app from a button in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to use a button to redirect from my actual app to another app, no to another activity, I refer to another app, but I only see answers to redirect to another activity in the same app, some help to do this between two apps?

Answer (score 3):

this is only valid if you know the package name of another app...

```
    String packageName = "packagename_of_other_app";
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if(intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise a intent, try like this:

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Where packageName would be package name of your another app.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of an "app" is not well-defined. To start the launch activity of a package:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my_co.my_app");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've omitted exception and null handling in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we may need the package name for this purpose

```
 String packageName = "com.musetheplace.rssfeed.activity";
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if(intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

or what you can do is

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.musetheplace.rssfeed.activity");
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mUri);
startActivity(mIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action in another app. for example

```
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.run" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Then, in you app, you just need to use this action string

```
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.run");
                startActivity(intent);
```